# Better way to filter a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries that has the structure similar to this one:

```
log = [{'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time1'},  
       {'user_id': 'id2', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time2'},
       ...]
```

and is sorted by timestamp value.

I would like to delete sequential identical actions done by the same user leaving just the first one, e.g. if I have the following list:

```
log = [{'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time1'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time2'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time3'},
       {'user_id': 'id2', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time4'},
       {'user_id': 'id3', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time5'},
       {'user_id': 'id3', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time6'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time7'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time8'}]
```

I would like to obtain this list as a result:

```
log = [{'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time1'},
       {'user_id': 'id2', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time4'},
       {'user_id': 'id3', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time5'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time7'}]
```

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
def merge_actions(log):
    merged_log = []
    merged_log.append(log[0])
    for i in range(1, len(log)):
        if log[i]['user_id'] == log[i-1]['user_id']:
            if log[i]['action'] == log[i-1]['action']:
                continue
        merged_log.append(log[i])
    return merged_log
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and group by the `'user_id'` and `'action'`, you can grab the first element out of each of the groups.

```
>>> [next(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(log, key = lambda i: (i['user_id'], i['action']))]
[{'timestamp': 'time1', 'action': 'action1', 'user_id': 'id1'},
 {'timestamp': 'time4', 'action': 'action2', 'user_id': 'id2'},
 {'timestamp': 'time5', 'action': 'action2', 'user_id': 'id3'},
 {'timestamp': 'time7', 'action': 'action1', 'user_id': 'id1'}]
```

Comment: `key=itemgetter('user_id','action')` will do the same job without the need for a lambda

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group sequential actions by the same user and then take the first element of each group:

```
def merge_actions(log):
    return [next(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(log, lambda l: (l['user_id'], l['action']))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use a loop you just need to simply keep track of the last key you saw:

```
it = iter(log)
start = next(it)
od,prev = [start], start["user_id"]
for d in it:
    k = d["user_id"]
    if prev != k:
        od.append(d)
    prev = k

print(od)

[{'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time1', 'user_id': 'id1'}, 
 {'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time4', 'user_id': 'id2'}, 
{'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time5', 'user_id': 'id3'}, 
{'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time7', 'user_id': 'id1'}]
```

If the actions are not always grouped check both keys:

```
it = iter(log)
start = next(it)
od, prev,act = [start], start["user_id"],start["action"]
for d in it:
    k1, k2 = d["user_id"], d["action"]
    if prev != k1 or k2 != act:
        od.append(d)
    prev, act = k1, k2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a verbose attempt at using `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
a = [{'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time1'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time2'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time3'},
       {'user_id': 'id2', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time4'},
       {'user_id': 'id3', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time5'},
       {'user_id': 'id3', 'action': 'action2', 'timestamp': 'time6'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time7'},
       {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time8'}]
for u, grps in groupby(a, lambda d: d['user_id']):
    d_with_first_ts = sorted(grps, key = lambda user_dict: user_dict['timestamp'])[0]
    print('User: {}; Dict with first timestamp = {}'.format(u, d_with_first_ts))
```

You will get the following results:

```
User: id1; Dict with first timestamp = {'timestamp': 'time1', 'action': 'action1', 'user_id': 'id1'}
User: id2; Dict with first timestamp = {'timestamp': 'time4', 'action': 'action2', 'user_id': 'id2'}
User: id3; Dict with first timestamp = {'timestamp': 'time5', 'action': 'action2', 'user_id': 'id3'}
User: id1; Dict with first timestamp = {'timestamp': 'time7', 'action': 'action1', 'user_id': 'id1'}
```

Comment: your example groups _all_ actions by user, while I would like to merge only sequential ones, i.e. the result should also contain

    {'user_id': 'id1', 'action': 'action1', 'timestamp': 'time7'}

Comment: In that case, you can ignore `sorted_users` line. I will update the code